# Can't always access value of instance variable without @ even with attr_accessor

Tags: ruby

How come I get the error `NoMethodError: undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass` but the line with `puts test` prints out a 1 so we know that the value is initialized?

```
class TestClass
  attr_accessor :test
  def initialize()
    @test = 1
  end

  def testFn
    puts test
    test = test + 1
  end
end

t = TestClass.new
t.testFn
```

It also works if I change `test` to `@test` but I thought I didn't have to if I had `attr_accessor :test`

Answer (score 1):

When you are assigning value to instance variable through accessor / writer, you have to use `self`, otherwise Ruby interpreter thinks it is a local variable. In your case, the testFn code should look like this:

```
def testFn
  puts test
  self.test = test + 1
end
```

Comment: Is it common to have an attr_accessor and then only use self to assign values while just directly using the value otherwise? Or do people generally use self for both assigning and reading to make it less confusing and have less chances of missing a self? @kallax